# strict standards: 5.0 method permission must be compatible with 4.0 permissionless method

Tags: php, oop

I have a report-generating class that extends a pdf class. The report-generating class is written in 5.0 style, where each method has a permission ( `public`, `private`, etc or whatever you call it). The base class was written in 4.0 style and doesn't have `public`, `private`, etc declaration for methods or variables.

I've recently turned on strict standards on our development machine, and now I'm getting errors that
`Strict standards: Declaration of reportPdf::stream() should be compatible with that of Cpdf::stream()`

But no matter what declaration I give to `stream()`, public, private, protected, or no permission at all, I still get this error.

Can I fix this? Or must I turn off strict standards while I'm working on this.

Migrating to a newer class is not an option at this point because it's too much work to for the functionality payoff. It works fine when strict standards are turned off.

---

**Edit:** I did some testing, and here's the matrix of results. No matter what, `Strict Standards` still complains.

`protected function stream() { ...`

```
Fatal error: Access level to reportPdf::stream() must be public (as in class Cpdf) in
```

`public function stream() { ...`

```
Strict standards: Declaration of reportPdf::stream() should be compatible with that of Cpdf::stream()
```

`private function stream() { ...`

```
Fatal error: Access level to reportPdf::stream() must be public (as in class Cpdf)
```

`function stream() { ...`

```
Strict standards: Declaration of reportPdf::stream() should be compatible with that of Cpdf::stream()
```

Also note that stream has 0 arguments, just like its parent class :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in code cleanliness if that makes the application fail. (= turn E_STRICT off)

That being said, I think the discrepancy lies most certainly in the parameters, not in the access modifiers. PHP would give another error else.

The `stream()` method might have more or fewer arguments in your derived `reportPdf` class, than in the pdf writer. If so, you can trick PHP by reversing the order in which in the classes are defined. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46851

Comment: "The stream() method might have more or fewer arguments" in the derived class, `stream()` has no arguments, just like in the parent class :(

Comment: @user151841: That's the common cultprit then. If so you might have luck with simply adding defaults for any extra parameters: `function stream($x=0, $y=NULL)`