# Singleton Pattern with a public constructor

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I want to implement Singleton Design Pattern to a class which extends another class with a public constructor in PHP. For example, consider a class, say Animal:

```
class Animal
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to implement Singleton Design Pattern to a class which extends Animal, for example:

```
class Dog extends Animal
{

    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

If I try to do `Dog::getInstance()` it gives an error

> Fatal error: Access level to Dog::__construct() must be public (as in
>   class Animal)

But if I make the constructor of class Dog public, then there's no point in implementing Singleton pattern to it.

Is there a workaround so that I can implement Singleton pattern to the class Dog while extending class Animal? OR Is there a better design pattern for achieving what I want?

I cannot modify `Animal` as it belongs to a library. I have full control over `Dog`. What I really want to achieve is for `Dog` to be able to extend `Animal`, but I don't want to have multiple instances of `Dog` being created.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a strict-standard error. If you declare constructor protected in parent class, it must be protected in inheriting class - [same protection lvl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549440/strict-standards-5-0-method-permission-must-be-compatible-with-4-0-permissionle).

Comment: just saying but should not you put the "static $instance = null;" inside the class but outside the getInstance() method ? Otherwise, i gonna instantiate a new Dog object each time since it will be equal to null.

Comment: @Cr3aHal0 No. The singleton pattern has been implemented well. This is how you do it in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Havelock Thanks for mentioning (anti-) pattern. I was easily able to implement what I want using Factory pattern. Here is my full code:

```
class Animal
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function run()
    {
        echo 'The dog runs';
    }
}

class DogFactory
{

    public static function create()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new Dog();
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}

$d = DogFactory::create();
$d->run();
```

Comment: You do know that posting and accepting answers to your own questions is absolutely legit on SO, right?! ;-)

Comment: @Havelock Yes, I do, but it appears that I will have to wait for 2 days before I can accept my own answer. I don't mind though since it leaves room for more suggestions and criticism

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the singleton pattern not an antipattern. It's formulated for a purpose. If you miss the purpose then you misuse it.

To your question:
Extending a class to make it a singleton does not make any sense. Especially if the API declines access to the construction as you encountered.

My suggestion:
Favor composition over inheritance. So create an own class without inheritance and apply the singletion pattern. ASSOCIATE an Animal-Object and delegate any method you want to the Animal-Object.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `Animal` as an `interface` and then you can keep the `Dog::__construct()` as protected.

> OR Is there a better design pattern for achieving what I want?

It's not clear what you'd like to achieve by implementing the singleton [(anti-) pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=singleton+antipattern), especially in the context of modelling an animal, so it's hard to answer this question. At the moment I can only think of database connection and registry (session) as viable use cases for using singleton (in the context of a web application of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot modify `Animal` as it belongs to a library. I have full control over `Dog` though. My main purpose is to somehow let `Dog` extend `Animal`, but I don't want anyone to be able to create multiple instances of it by doing `new Dog()`

Answer (score -2):

Please see it's your right answer or not.

```
class Animal
{

    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }    
}
```